# check if a div has an img element inside using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I'm doing a drag and drop using jquery of a picture to a target div.

I have a button that calls a function that should check that the image is inside the div, but I can not get it to work correctly.

I'm trying to do as follows:

```
<script>
    ....

    $( '#check' ).click(function(){
        if($("#droptarget:has(img.img1)")){
            alert("yes");
        }else{
            alert("no");
        }
    });
</script>

<img id="img1" class="img1" src="image.png">
<div id="droptarget"></div>
<a href="javascript:" id="check">check</a>
```

What's wrong in my code?

EDIT: always enters on the first condition doing the alert("yes") without the image inside the div

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `$()` always a jQuery object which makes it truthy, try

```
$( '#check' ).click(function(){
    if($("#droptarget:has(img.img1)").length > 0){
        alert("yes");
    }else{
        alert("no");
    }
});
```

This checks to see if there are any matches to the selector `#droptarget:has(img.img1)`

Answer (score 0):

Your script is above `#check`, so the click event does not get bound.  Use `$(document).ready` (or just `$(...`) OR just move your script to below `#check`.